# Weird race condition by using ViewModel-first (binding) approach

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, command, race-condition

I am experimenting with a simple ViewModel-first based WPF application and some primitive navigation logic. The application consists of two views (screens). One screen contains a button "Go forward" and the other a button "Go backward". By pressing one of the buttons a delegate command is invoked, which in turn causes the shell view-model to switch the active screen. Screen 1 switches to Screen 2, whereas Screen 2 switches to Screen 1.

The problem with this approach is, that it introduces a race condition. When  clicking fast enough there is a chance that the corresponding action (go forward/go backward) is executed twice, thus causing the application to fail. The interesting thing about that is that the screen has already been changed, but the UI doesn't reflect the state changes instantaneously. Until now I never had experienced this kind of gap and I made this experiment just to prove, that a single-threaded (dispatched) WPF application is automatically thread-safe.

Does somebody have an explanation for this odd behavior? Is the WPF binding mechanism too slow, so that the button can be pressed a second time, until the UI has updated itself to represent the new screen state?

I have no idea how to fix this according to the recommendations for developing mvvm applications. There is no way to synchronize the code, because there is only one thread. I hope you can help me, because now I feel very unsecure with relying on the WPF data binding and templating system.

[Zip archive containing the project files](http://en.file-upload.net/download-11230590/WPF_race_condition.zip.html)

[image: Screen 1 switches to Screen 2, whereas Screen 2 switches to Screen 1. By clicking fast enough it is possible to introduce a race condition (that is going forward/backward twice).]

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Screen1}">
            <local:View1/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Screen2}">
            <local:View2/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ShellViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentScreen}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The **ShellViewModel** containing a "go forward" and "go backward" method:

```
Public Class ShellViewModel
    Inherits PropertyChangedBase

    Private _currentScreen As Object
    Public Property Screens As Stack(Of Object) = New Stack(Of Object)()

    Public Sub New()
        Me.Screens.Push(New Screen1(Me))
        Me.GoForward()
    End Sub

    Property CurrentScreen As Object
        Get
            Return _currentScreen
        End Get
        Set(value)
            _currentScreen = value
            RaisePropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub GoBack()
        Log("Going backward.")
        If (Me.Screens.Count > 2) Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException("Race condition detected.")
        End If
        Log("Switching to Screen 1")
        Me.Screens.Pop()
        Me.CurrentScreen = Me.Screens.Peek()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GoForward()
        Log("Going forward.")
        If (Me.Screens.Count > 1) Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException("Race condition detected.")
        End If
        Log("Switching to Screen 2.")

        Me.Screens.Push(New Screen2(Me))
        Me.CurrentScreen = Me.Screens.Peek()
    End Sub

End Class
```

The **Screen** class containing just a delegate command to start the action:

```
Public Class Screen1
    Inherits PropertyChangedBase

    Private _clickCommand As ICommand
    Private _shellViewModel As ShellViewModel

    Public Sub New(parent As ShellViewModel)
        _shellViewModel = parent
    End Sub


    Public ReadOnly Property ClickCommand As ICommand
        Get
            If _clickCommand Is Nothing Then
                _clickCommand = New RelayCommand(AddressOf ExecuteClick, AddressOf CanExecute)
            End If
            Return _clickCommand
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Function CanExecute(arg As Object) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function

    Private Sub ExecuteClick(obj As Object)
        Threading.Thread.SpinWait(100000000)
        _shellViewModel.GoForward()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: No idea of a solution, but what I'd do... Try using a lock and a check when navigating.  The check should be some indication if the navigation is valid and it should check the current state of the application (break mvvm if you have to, temporarily).  Use the "check lock check" pattern. I'd watch the state of the application until the first check passes but the second doesn't, and that's where I'd take a good hard look at wtf is going on.

Comment: Thank you. Using a lock won't help me, because there aren't multiple threads accessing a shared resource. There is only the UI/dispatcher thread. I already implemented a simple logger to track the different steps, but so far I just know that in some cases the go back/go forward-methods are executed twice (but not at the same time). My next step is to write a log about whether the same instances triggered the additional command execution or if it is triggered by newly created objects.

Comment: You should post a complete reproduction as an example. The dispatcher uses priority queues. When using begininvoke from other threads it could even deadlock.       The following makes i < 0. this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (Action)(() => this.i++));
      this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => this.i--));

Comment: I posted a hyperlink to a zip archive containing the project files. My application doesn't make use of 'BeginInvoke', therefore I wouldn't expect race conditions to happen. It completely runs synchronously.

Answer (score 5):

#### There is no weird race condition

I've run your code. There is one thread. The main one.

```
One thread = no race condition.
```

Why do you want to prove the following ?

> I made this experiment just to prove, that a single-threaded
>   (dispatched) WPF application is automatically thread-safe.

It's a bullet proof fact. **One thread = thread safe** (as long as you don't share data process wide, but then it's not thread safety anymore).

#### Binding and Method no supporting successive calls

In fact, your methods GoBack and GoForward are not supporting successive calls. They should be called one after another.

Thread safety here doesn't imply that your methods cannot be call twice in a row. If there is any task queue in the process, methods can be called twice.

*What you may intend to prove is maybe the following:*

> Clicks are captured and processed in line, without any task queuing between
>   the click, the property changed event raised, the dispatcher
>   invocation, the binding / display refresh.

**It's clearly Wrong!**

When you call Dispatcher.BeginInvoke or Invoke, it's using internally a **queue of tasks**. And nothing prevent you from queuing **twice the same task** coming from **two similar clicks** for example.

To be frank, I was unable to reproduce your bug. I think it's the same thread that captures clicks that dispatch it to your code and then display it on screen. However since task for click events, display refresh are in the same queue, it is theoretically possible to enqueue two clicks before screen change. However :

- I cannot click fast enough to beat my cpu.
- I don't think the SpinWait are needed.
- Something may miss in my configuration.

**Why not making your methods supporting successive calls ?**

GoBack and GoBackward could check a status and do nothing if the current status is not valid.

You could have used:

**1. Two screens both instantiated from the start.**

**2. A `bool` to indicate the current state (Forward or Back).**

**3. An `enum` to be more clearer in code.**

**4. A state machine..** *no! I'm kidding.*

*Note: Why using a Stack to push and pop screen(only one by the way) ? and...
in case, you add another thread: 
**Stack pop / push are not thread safe.**
Instead use **[`ConcurrentStack<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)***

Comment: Searching for the cause of another obscure issue, I have come across another example that proves you wrong! Even if a single-threaded application is by definition thread-safe, that doesn't mean that there can't be any race conditions. In fact UI scheduling can lead to race conditions that are similar to those which are related to threading.

Comment: I have added an answer for demonstrating this.

Answer (score 2):

#### Simulation

Even when the UI thread is frozen or doing something, another inputs are being collected. Try this out (Sorry for C# but you get the point):

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("start");
        Thread.Sleep(6000);
        Debug.WriteLine("End");
    }
```

Click the button, then place a breakpoint on the Start line, click the button again before the UI thread unfreezes. and you will see that exactly 6 seconds after your first click the breakpoint gets hit.

#### Explanation

The UI thread can obviously only perform 1 action at a time, but it has to be optimized for multithreading - meaning it queues it's actions. Therefore any PropertyChanged (or any handler at all including the OnClick) is only queueing the action for the UI thread. It doesn't jump out of your code to update the UI elements in the middle of your setter. If you call Thread.Sleep after the setter you will see that you don't see any change - because the UI thread didn't get to invoke the update yet.

#### Why is this important

In your code you first Push a screen and then set is as current, calling propertyChanged. That does not change the screens immediately, it just queues it for the update. There is no guarantee that another click doesn't get scheduled before that.

You could also achieve freezing your UI thread by calling PropertyChanged a million times causing it to freeze during the update itself. Yet the clicks in the meantime would be collected.

So your "safepoint" - the place where it is safe that no other click can be scheduled now - is not after the Setter is finished, but after the Loaded Event is called on the new window.

#### How to fix

Read 
[Fab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5328150/fab)
's answer :)

Dont think that just because the UI thread is blocked at the moment nothing gets in. If you want to disable inputs while something is being calculated you do need to disable the inputs manually.

Possible solutions

1. Set IsEnabled, Visibility, IsHitTestVisible
2. Some Overlay or whatever
3. Boolean parameter, that could globally allow or disallow all methods coming (basically a lock)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the described behavior - double clicking causes the app to first "go backward", and then "go forward" at my side. Nevertheless, I think that expecting the button to disappear before the user can click it for the second time is not a good design (especially in case of devices that for instance have a separate "double-click" button), and I would personally never rely on that.

What I think is the best way to proceed in this situation is to properly implement the `CanExecute` method, so that it not only returns `true` (which by the way is most likely redundant), but rather queries the `_shellViewModel` whether it's in a state allowing to invoke the method called by `ExecuteClick` (in case of `GoForward` it should return `true` if there is only one element on the stack). I cannot test that (because I cannot reproduce the behavior in question), but I'm pretty sure that even if the user clicks the same button twice, the second call to `CanExecute` will occur after the first call to `ExecuteClick`, thus the model will be guaranteed to be "up-to-date" (the result will be `false` and `GoForward` will not be called again).

Answer (score 1):

@**Pavel Kalandra**:

While it is possible for a simple click event-handler to be queued multiple times, even if the UI thread is blocked, I can't reproduce this behavior with a delegate command. Hence I assume that the WPF framework does handle the invocation of an command a little bit differently compared to a simple click event-handler. Moreover, in your example the click event is already queued before the execution of the event-handler has  finished. In my situation this is not the case.

To prove this assumption I made a further experiment: By using a command that blocks the UI thread for a few seconds and then shows a message, you can see that it is not possible to invoke it multiple times during its invocation. I believe that the WPF framework is somehow preventing this from happening. Therefore both scenarios aren't comparable to one.

But I think that your explanation is still correct. Pushing the screen causes the PropertyChanged-event to be fired, but the screen is not updated immediately. Indeed the associated job is pushed onto the dispatcher queue and is scheduled. As a consequence there is a short time span during which it is possible to invoke the command a second time.

@**Fab**:

When you strongly rely on the accepted definition of a race condition, then there shouldn't be one in my sample application. But for simplicity purposes I would like to call it still a race condition because the scheduling of jobs makes the execution nondeterministic.

Nevertheless, the assumption I was intended to prove, is wrong. I wanted to prove it because of threading problems we are currently faced with. Our application simulates multiple modal methods at the same time, therefore it relies on multiple threads. Because the interactions, a user is allowed to, aren't properly synchronized there is a high chance for race conditions to happen (synchronizing them is not an option because of other reasons).

At the moment I am working on a prototype which doesn't use threads so heavily. My hope was, that by executing everything on the dispatcher thread race conditions (or similar problems) shouldn't be possible. At least for a ViewModel-first approach this seems to be wrong because of the way the WPF is scheduling binding updates.

I have used a simple scenario where it is easy to provide a fix to the potential "race condition". But in general it won't be easy to write a Bulletproof WPF application. A flag to indicate the direction (forward/backward) won't be enough when dealing with multiple screens. But the command delegate could check if it is invoked from the active screen.

PS: As long as I rely exclusively on the dispatcher thread to execute actions, I see no need for using a ConcurrentStack ;-)

Comment: Beware of the false assumption that there can only be one dispatcher at a time. In fact, WPF supports several dispatcher (each which one thread). Controls are bound to the dispatcher-thread couple on which there were created. In order to reproduce a problem similar to your production application, you may have use several thread/dispatchers.

Comment: And beware also of the CurrentDispatcher which can create a new Dispatcher :). Btw, I'm interested in why you cannot use some sort of synchronization ? (either lock or task queue or lock free algorithm)

Comment: You are right. There may be more than one dispatcher. But as long as all Window instances are created on the same thread there sould be only one. It is hard to explain why we cannot synchronize it properly. Basically there are several actions (OnItemSelected, OnCommand etc.). Within these methods we simulate modal user inputs (methods not returning immediately). While a modal input box is shown it must be still possible to cancel it by executing one of the other actions. Therefore only one action can be locked at the same time. Otherwise they would deadlock themselves. This is a design flaw.

Comment: Because it is not possible to fix this problem without radically changing the underlying architecture, we are now experimenting with prototypes.

Comment: I suggest you to create another question then with the root problem(s), what you try to achieve and what are your constraints (underlying architecture cannot change).

Comment: I probably will open another question. But at least I have a simple explanation for our threading problems. The WPF issue was something I was very surprised about ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have come across another similar issue, that proves that UI scheduling can in fact introduce race conditions even if the application is single-threaded.
In the example a piece of code is called, that is supposed to be atomic. Because scheduling is used using different priorities, the code may be interrupted in the middle of execution.

This is an example that I found in a similar form in our production code. Users have mentioned an issue that is spontaneously occuring. I have found out then that a SelectionChanged-event was interrupting a piece of code that was supposed to be executed as a block.

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private bool inBetweenMethod;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Loaded);
            this.timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
            this.timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            this.timer.Start();
            this.MethodThatIsSupposedToBeAtomic();

        }


        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (inBetweenMethod)
            {
                throw new Exception("Method was interrupted in the middle of execution".);
            }
        }


        private void MethodThatIsSupposedToBeAtomic()
        {
            inBetweenMethod = true;
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("iterating");
                }
            }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);


            inBetweenMethod = false;

        }
}
```